# Signing and verifying text with key pairs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, pgp, gnupg

Is there any library available (or well-written algorithm reference I could implement) that would allow me to sign a piece of text with a private key, preferably my existing SSH (RSA) or PGP key?

My goal is to write a bookmarklet to sign my blog posts, and provide another bookmarklet to allow others to verify them. I'm not trying to do any kind of secure communication. I just thought it might be neat to be able to store the public keys of others and use them to verify authorship automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately such design raises several security-related questions, eg. how to prevent spoofing of keys (if they are downloaded from the server) or how to pick keys from the local storage (if local ones are used). Then the question is how verification should be performed (the user needs either to trust the key and have the trusted key at hand, or use PKI for certificate validation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one? [PGP / GnuPG / OpenPGP Message Encryption in JavaScript](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into jCryption: http://www.jcryption.org/

It's made to encrypt forms using ajax, but it may be somewhere to get started.